# MVC / AJAX send data to controller and load response in same view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with three form fields (2 textbox, 1 dropdown), a submit button and a 'refresh' link. I want to be able to click the link and pass two form textbox values to a controller action, and get a list of values to populate the dropdown box. I do not want to submit the form at this stage.

At the moment, I have managed to call the controller action from the link click, but I cannot pass the two form field values in for some reason. Also, the return JSON just takes me to a new page instead of populating my dropdown list. Any pointers would be great as I am new to javascript and MVC. My code is below;

Controller

```
public ActionResult Find(AddressFormViewModel model)
{
    ...
    var temp = new List<OptionModel>();
    temp.Add(new OptionModel {Id = item.Id, Value = item.desc});
    return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

HTML

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.HouseNameInput, new { id = "HouseNameInput" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.PostCodeInput, new { id = "PostCodeInput" })
@Html.ActionLink("Find","Find", "Address", new { houseInput = Model.HouseNameInput, postcodeInput = Model.PostCodeInput }, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "Find" } })

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AddressOption, Enumerable.Empty<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>(), "-- Loading Values --", new {id = "AddressOptions"})
```

And lastly, my Javascript method which is retrieving the data from the controller action but not populating the dropdown list (it displays the results in a new page). It is also not successfully sending the form values to the controller action.

```
    $(function () {
    $('.Find').click(function (evt) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Find","AddressFormSurface")',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                houseNameInput: $("#HouseNameInput").value,
                postCodeInput: $("#PostCodeInput").value
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.exists) {
                    var ddl = $('#AddressOptions');
                    ddl.empty();

                    data.each(function () {
                        $(document.createElement('option'))
                            .attr('value', this.Id)
                            .text(this.Value)
                            .appendTo(ddl);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (req) {

            }
        });

        // we make sure to cancel the default action of the link
        // because we will be sending an AJAX call
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: First remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. And suggest you just use `<a href="#" id="find">Find</a>` rather than the helper (there is no point in adding the rote values etc) and the use `$('#find').click() {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke right but in your case you can just write `evt.preventDefault();` before `$.ajax` and i gess it will work

Comment: @teovankot, OP already has `return false;` at the end of the script, but clearly the script is not running if it doing a redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok, my bad =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of errors in your script which will cause it to fail.

1. You specify `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` but do
   not stringify the data (the option should be removed)
2. You need to use `.val()` (not `.value`) to get the values of the
   inputs
3. The data you receiving does not contain a property named `exists` so
   the `if` block where you append the options will never be hit

In addition it is unnecessary to generate your link using `@Html.ActionLink()` (your adding route values based on the initial values of the model). Instead just create it manually

```
<a href="#" id="find">Find</a>
```

and change the script to

```
var ddl = $('#AddressOptions'); // cache it
$('#find').click(function () { // change selector
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', // its a GET, not a POST
        url: '@Url.Action("Find","AddressFormSurface")', // see side note below
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            houseNameInput: $("#HouseNameInput").val(),
            postCodeInput: $("#PostCodeInput").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                // oops
                return;
            }
            ddl.empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $(document.createElement('option'))
                    .attr('value', item.Id)
                    .text(item.Value)
                    .appendTo(ddl);
                // or ddl.append($('<option></option>').text(item.Value).val(item.Id));
            });
        },
        error: function (req) {
            ....
        }
    }
});
```

Side note: Also check the name of the controller. Your `Html.ActionLink()` suggests its `AddressController` but your script is calling `AddressFormSurfaceController`

Comment: Thanks so much!  I will test this in the morning and update with / as answer

Comment: Works perfectly.  The error: param is in the wrong section though.  Thanks for the help!